# Where to save trial status file on windows

Tags: c#, windows, file

The program shall have a 14 day trial period. Therefore, somewhere on the machine I want to save when the trial begun. It should be somewhere, where it doesn't get deleted. What is the best place?
(it should be locally on the machine, not a cloud solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the install date in the registry. It is not fool proof as the entry could still be deleted, but it is a quite common solution.

Comment: Where exactly in the registry would this be?